# Why regex not matches using java classes or JRegex classes?

Tags: java, regex

I'm using the regex bottom for validate strings like:

c:\folder1

x:\folder-a

Regex 1:
^(?:[a-zA-Z]:(\|/)|file://|\\|.(/|\))([^\/:*\?\<>\"\|]+(\|/){0,1})+$

Regex 2:
([A-Z]:\[^/:*\?<>\|]+.\w{2,6})|(\{2}[^/:*\?<>\|]+.\w{2,6})

I verified regex online on various sites and they match but not match with java\java libraries:

Example:

```
String regex = ...load string from file...
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher("c:\\folder1");
m.matches(); //return false
m.find(); //return false
```

in debug mode the expression:

```
regex.equals("pasted regex manually")
returns true for both regex
```

I verified the regex and have no intruders characters.

The behavior occurs with both Java and JRegex classes.

Why ?
what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you get the pattern from a file, you don't need to escape backslashes since it's only needed when you want to represent a string in a variable. Also, most of your escapes are useless. Test with:

Regex1:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]:[\\/]|file://|\\\\|\.[\\/])([^\\:*?<>"|]+[\\/]?)+$
```

Regex2:

```
([A-Z]:\\[^/:*\\?<>|]+.\w{2,6})|(\\\\[^/:*\\?<>|]+.\w{2,6})
```